# Chromium Client Hints: how to set several urls in Delegate-CH meta tags?

Tags: html, google-chrome, client-hints

I have set the meta tags like this:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Accept-CH" content="Sec-CH-UA, Sec-CH-UA-Full-Version-List, Sec-CH-UA-Model, Sec-CH-UA-Mobile, Sec-CH-UA-Platform, Sec-CH-UA-Platform-Version" >
<meta http-equiv="Delegate-CH" content="Sec-CH-UA https://example1.com; https://example2.com; Sec-CH-UA-Full-Version-List https://example1.com; https://example2.com; Sec-CH-UA-Model https://example1.com; https://example2.com; Sec-CH-UA-Mobile https://example1.com; https://example2.com; Sec-CH-UA-Platform https://example1.com; https://example2.com; Sec-CH-UA-Platform-Version https://example1.com; https://example2.com;" >
```

My testpage has https, and I get the requested headers for the first url, in this example example1.com. However, for the second entry, example2.com in the example, I don't get all the client hint headers. What is the right way to define several urls in the meta tag?

Edit: it actually works if I set a second meta tag for the second url - however I wonder if that's the way it is supposed to work...

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<meta>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-meta-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: You are right, thanks for the hint

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: just have an empty space between tbe urls, and a semicolon after the last url. So in my example, just remove every semicolon after example1.com